# how Handy Control don't effect on my App theme?

Tags: wpf, farsi

I want to use `PersianDatepicker` in my `WPF` App. I use `HandyControl` For That. but when use it in my App All of My App themes changed.

I use this Tag in my `App.xaml`

```html
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
        <hc:ThemeResources />
        <hc:Theme />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Now I don't want this package to affect the All of My App themes.

Comment: Then dont add <hc:ThemeResources /> and <hc:Theme /> in your App.xaml. use it only in a specific context

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in a specific `UserControl` and add config in it's resource like this:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
    x:Name="UserControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <hc:Theme />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
            <hc:PersianDateTimePicker
                Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerExtendPersian}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: can you description step by step Please?

Comment: You do not need to add configs in `App.xaml`, only You can create a new control and add configs in its `Resources`, therefore only that control theme will be affeced.